# Mouseover tip on excel checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry to trouble you all, but I looked everywhere and did not find what I was aiming for.

I have a spreadsheet in Excel with multiple checkboxes. Each one has an specific concept displayed next to it.

I want to show a definition for each concept in a cell below the checkboxes when the user hovers the mouse over the checkbox so that he can have a definition for what he is choosing.

I made a mock version in the image below.

[image]
How can I achieve this effect?

Also, after user clicks and moves mouse away it should restart to the initial message (Move mouse over to show tip)

Can someone help please? Frustrated and desperate here.

Please be specific on implementation...

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseMove()` event is the one to use and it is documented [behind this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mousemove-event)

When designing your form (sheet), you need to use the ActiveX checkboxes as they provide the `MouseMove()` events. In my sample code below, I used the ActiveX label to display the messages. Place the checkboxes and the label on a common control. I was looking for a panel, but could not find one, so I used an ActiveX `Image` control. The purpose of the panel / image is only to provide an event to reset the message when the mouse moves away from either checkbox.

**Edit**: The `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame` control from `Additional controls` might be a better selection to host the checkboxes and the label.

To write the events open the Visual Basic editor and select the sheet where you placed the checkboxes  and labels. In the editor window select one checkbox in the left drop down, and the `MouseMove` event in the right dropdown.

Fill in the code as needed, f.ex.:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Label1.Caption = "This is simply the explanation of what CheckBox1 does."
End Sub
```

Then select the other checkbox and the event, then fill in as needed:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Label1.Caption = "This is simply the explanation of what CheckBox2 does."
End Sub
```

And finally select the panel / image on which the other controls are placed and the `MouseMove`event. Then fill in the code to reset the initial message:

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Label1.Caption = "Message reset"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ideas... This code is to create an effect as the one you mention with images (on local or external route, so in you case will be a textbox, just replace it) and it is  working as soon as you place your mouse in top of the URL mention, so you will use your check box. It can not be more specific as you did not provide additional information.

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean

Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 200
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

DoOnce it is a general variable. OnMouseOver shows one image and Reset Hide the image.
Hope it helps